# How to get the value from json with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, pubmed

How can I get the source, title, issn, author, ... from a json file: [JSON file](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=29539636&retmode=json)

We tried with:

```
$new_pmid = $_POST['new_pmid'];
$api_json_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=".$new_pmid."&retmode=json";                          
$json = file_get_contents($api_json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo $header[0]->result->$new_pmid->title;  
....
```

But nothing happen...

Can you give me the solution for the json file (generated from pubmed database).

Thank you.

Comment: You are echoing out your $header.  Your results are in the $data variable.  print_r($data) and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `$data` variable, which stored the decoded data

Answer (score 0):

You decode JSON into `$data` as array

```
$title = $data['result'][$new_pmid]['title'];
$issn = $data['result'][$new_pmid]['issn'];
$authors = $data['result'][$new_pmid]['authors'];
```

**--Update--**

To get `$authors` name ,authtype ,... use foreach loop:

```
foreach($authors as $author){
    $name = $author['name'];
    $authtype = $author['authtype'];
    $clusterid = $author['clusterid'];
}
```

Comment: For title ann issn are OK now. But for authors, how can I get the list from an array?

Comment: @NguyenHoangBach Yes by above code you store "authors" array into `$authors`, the answer was updated.

Comment: Thanks @aidinMC , I just want to make a full authors (13 authors in one line). According to you suggestion, when I show the author list, only last author appear. `$api_json_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=".$new_pmid."&retmode=json";       
   $json = file_get_contents($api_json_url);
   $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
   $authors =  $data['result'][$new_pmid]['authors'];
  
   foreach($authors as $author){
   $name = $author['name'];

   }`  and `echo "$name";` How to get the full list. Thank you so much